# Programmatically created CheckBoxList not firing when "unchecked"

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I'm using ASP.NET and C#. I'm programmtically creating a checkboxlist. When I check an item, the SelectedIndexChanged event is firing. But, when I uncheck the item, the event is not fired. I'm binding the items on every postback and autopostback is set to true. Where am I going wrong? Here's the code -

```
page_load
{

    var cblUser = new CheckBoxList();
    cblUser.AutoPostBack = true;
    cblUser.SelectedIndexChanged += cblUser_SelectedIndexChanged;

    var list = DAL.GetUsers();
    foreach (var user in list)
    {
        cblUser.Items.Add(new ListItem(user.Name, user.Id));
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Update #1: Actual code -

```
public partial class CategoriesAccordion : UserControl
    {
        public List<Community> AllCommunities
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["AllCommunities"] == null)
                {
                    var db = new CommunityGuideDB();
                    Session["AllCommunities"] = db.Communities.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
                }
                return (List<Community>) Session["AllCommunities"];
            }
        }

        public List<Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["Categories"] == null)
                {
                    var db = new CommunityGuideDB();
                    Session["Categories"] = db.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
                }
                return (List<Category>) Session["Categories"];
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler Categories_Selected = delegate { };

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) Session.Remove("Categories");
            LoadCategories();
        }

        private void LoadCategories()
        {
            foreach (var parent in Categories.Where(item => item.ParentId == null && item.ShowAsPivot == true).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
            {
                var pane = new AccordionPane {ID = parent.Name};
                pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(parent.Name));

                var cblValues = new CheckBoxList();
                cblValues.AutoPostBack = true;
                cblValues.SelectedIndexChanged += cblValues_SelectedIndexChanged;
                foreach (var child in Categories.Where(child => child.ParentId == parent.Id))
                {
                    var communityCount = child.CommunityCategory.Where(x => x.Categories_Id == child.Id).Count();
                    cblValues.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Format("{0} ({1})", child.Name, communityCount), child.Id.ToString()));
                }

                pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(cblValues);
                acdFilters.Panes.Add(pane);
            }
        }

        protected void cblValues_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cblValues = ((CheckBoxList) sender);
            var selectedCategories = (from ListItem item in cblValues.Items where item.Selected select Categories.Find(c => c.Id == new Guid(item.Value))).ToList();
            Categories_Selected(this, new CommandEventArgs("SelectedCategories", selectedCategories));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get how do you add the control to a container?
I've just checked and I've got the event fired both on checking & unchecking.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList cbList = new CheckBoxList();
        cbList.AutoPostBack = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)            
            cbList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        cbList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cbList_SelectedIndexChanged);
        form1.Controls.Add(cbList);
    }

    void cbList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //fires both on check & uncheck of an item
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa! It does fire on both check and uncheck!!! I'm actually building the checkboxlist and binding it to an AJAX Accordion control. I've updated my question with the actual code. Can you see what's happening?

Comment: I can only guess that the issue is related to an AccordionPanel. Unfortunately I have no experience with it. Try to construct a test case as simple as possible (only one AccordionPanel, fixed set of items etc) so you can locate the root of your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedIndexChanged event you are bounding is fired upon selecting different item on your list, not when you check an item. CheckBoxList does not have an event for changing the status of its items.

### Try a to use list control like Repeater ...